# Does keeping the object structure consistent in JavaScript object literal help performance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, memory

For example, there are objects that have similar structure but not exactly the same.

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'john', age: 12 },
  { name: 'marry', age: 24, married: true }
]
```

or

```
const obj = {
  john: { age: 12 },
  marry: { age: 24, married: true }
}
```

Let's say John is not married so he does not need `married` key. (Though it might be better to have 'married' as false for consistency.) This might not be a perfect example, but in either case is including `married` key and keeping the object structure consistent help performance by any chance? e.g. Maybe it might help CPU write the data to the memory faster...?

Comment: A very tiny bit, due to hidden classes - but it's really not worth worrying about

Comment: "*Maybe it might help cpu write the data to the memory faster...?*" the real question would be "Is this even a measurable performance difference and does it help me in any way? Did I just waste vastly more time writing this question than I'd ever gain back by optimising my code in all application I'd ever write for the rest of my life?"

Comment: @VLAZ: You might be surprised; implementation details can make a big difference here. CPython for example uses a key-sharing dictionary optimization for class instances under the hood; if you reliably initialize all attributes during `__init__` in the same order, and don't delete or create new attributes later, the per-instance memory overhead is roughly halved; meaningless if you make 100 objects, important for 100M. I know nothing about what the various JS interpreters/JIT-ers may do to optimize such objects, but if you're making a lot of them, it might actually matter.

Comment: Just my opinion, but these days focusing on code security is much more important than micro optimizations like this. Optimizing this is very unlikely to result in a noticable performance improvement

Comment: @ControlAltDel: That's true, but it's also pretty tautological. Microoptimizations almost never mattered outside the hottest code (usually found in shared libraries where it's going to be used by hundreds of programs or more), and security was always important (even if people didn't realize it). There's nothing wrong with learning about how stuff like this affects performance; security and this sort of microoptimization are essentially unrelated.

Comment: @ShadowRanger "surprised" is quite a strong descriptor. I am aware that there are various optimisations done based on the shape of objects. I just don't think it's worth keeping any of them in mind unless there is an actual performance problem that you've profiled. Nowadays JS engines are *very* good at optimising code. Moreover, they keep improving all the time. If you try to change your objects shape to appease the optimisation, that might become obsolete before your code hits production. We just keep getting problemless questions where wouldn't matter even if optimisation could happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard disclaimers aside (everything said here may vary between engines, or even between different versions of the same engine, this is just an implementation detail, measure before optimizing, think twice before optimizing at the expense of readability, blah blah blah…), I think it’s reasonable to answer this with a cautious ‘yes’.  At the very least, it shouldn’t *hurt* to ensure objects always have the same shape.

In the case of V8 in particular, there is the somewhat well-known [hidden class optimization](https://v8.dev/docs/hidden-classes), which optimizes memory layout of objects based on their dynamically-profiled contents.  With fewer object shapes at runtime, there will be fewer hidden classes to track, and the ones that are there can be reused in more situations.  The engine will also not have to look up cached data for multiple hidden classes, which can decrease CPU cache contention.

What constitutes an object’s ‘shape’ will of course vary, but there are a number of characteristics you can expect to be relevant:

- What properties are present;
- In which order properties are added to the object (sensitivity to this is sometimes called *path dependence*);
- Whether the properties are modified after construction;
- The *types* of values held in those properties, and even particular sub-ranges of those types (e.g. V8 is known to store integers in the range [−2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup>) more efficiently than other numbers, even as the JS number type nominally covers all IEEE 754 doubles).

Though the above is mostly based on V8, you can expect any other optimizing JavaScript engine to perform roughly similar optimizations based on object shape.  In fact, even the relatively naïve QuickJS caches object shapes to speed up property lookups.

And writing your code in a way that ensures that objects of conceptually the same ‘type’ have consistent shapes (for example, by having them always constructed in a single place in code, where the same properties are added in the same order) much of the time should not even hurt readability — on the contrary, it might even make code more easily comprehensible.  Unlike some other micro-optimizations, I think this one is definitely worth doing to at least some extent.

Answer (score 1):

The performance benefits are:

1. Almost certainly tiny, and
2. Almost certainly going to vary between JS engines

and aren't worth worrying about unless:

1. Your code is running too slow, and
2. Profiling implicates the section of the code that is concerned with creating/manipulating these objects

The real concern is maintainability. Maintaining a consistent set of attributes for logically related objects is a good thing, even if it's unnecessary; if someone wants to build on your code, it's nice if they can rely on a fixed set of attributes for a given collection of objects. Default to including the extra attributes consistently; if you get a performance boost, that's just gravy.